# Can't unsubscribe from BehaviourSubject with piped timer

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a `BehaviorSubject`:

```
private interval$: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject(10);
```

Its' value is used for a timer, in order to `tap` something new every `value` seconds:

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.interval$.pipe(
      switchMap(value => timer(0, value * 1000)),
      takeWhile(() => this.isPlaying),
      tap(() => console.log('Hi!'))
    ).subscribe();
}
```

I want to stop the subscription when the component is destroyed. I tried:

```
ngOnDestroy(){
  this.interval$.unsubscribe();
}
```

and also

```
ngOnDestroy(){
  this.isPlaying = false;
}
```

[Here's a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-v9zstw) that simulates the problem.

But `Hi` keeps printing on and on. What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried:  

intervalSubscription$: Subscription = this.interva$ ....

this.intervalSubscription$.unsubscribe()

Comment: @LeonLafayette yes. I also tried using subscription.add(this.interval$...) and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

subscribe() return subscription then in ngOnDestory unsubscribe it.

Please check highlighted lines

[image]

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
        this.subscription =this.interval$.pipe(
          switchMap(value => timer(0, value * 1000)),
          takeWhile(() => this.isPlaying),
          tap(() => console.log('Hi!'))
        ).subscribe();
    }
    
    ngOnDestory(){
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
```

another thing make ur life easy and use [untilDestroyed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-take-until-destroy) it will automatically unsubscribe on destroy.

```
this.interval$.pipe(
              untilDestroyed(this),
              switchMap(value => timer(0, value * 1000)),
              takeWhile(() => this.isPlaying),
              tap(() => console.log('Hi!'))
            ).subscribe();
```

U just have to implement [OnDestory](https://angular.io/api/core/OnDestroy) interface

Comment: create a demo in stackblatz and show me code there I will hlep u

Comment: here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-v9zstw. For simplicity I added a button that calls `unsubscribe` instead of implementing `OnDestroy`.

Comment: Thanks @hanan, I guess I didn't implement it correctly the first time

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the substcription:

```
private intervalSubscription: Subscription;
```

In the ngAfterViewInit:

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.intervalSubscription = this.interval$.pipe(
      switchMap(value => timer(0, value * 1000)),
      takeWhile(() => this.isPlaying),
      tap(() => console.log('Hi!'))
    ).subscribe();
}
```

In the ngOnDestory:

```
ngOnDestory(){
   this.intervalSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```